# How do you use SinonJS for callback methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai

So I have this method I want to test:

```
app.get('/test', exposeDb, function(req, res) {
    req.dbService.getUserByID( function(err, result) {
        if (result == 5) {
            res.statusCode = 200;
        }
        else {
            res.statusCode = 500;            
        }
    });
});
```

And I'm trying to stub it so the getUserByID method returns a value so I do this:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        var getUserByIDStubE = sinon.stub(dbService, 'getUserByID').callsFake(() => {
            return 5;
        });
      });

    it('TESTSETSTETS', function(done) {        
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/test')
            .send({})
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.should.have.status(200);
            });
            done();
    });
});
```

The problem is, the code inside the req.dbService.getUserByID is never called so I can't check the logic of whether the "result" is equal to 5 or not.

If I console.log(req.dbService.getUserByID()), that indeed returns the stubbed value of 5. But I do not know how it works on callback.

How do I make it so it returns 5 in my example (to then check the res.statusCode)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're function is getting a callback and calling that with the result, and not returning the result as your stub.

Try like this:

```
sinon.stub(dbService, 'getUserByID').callsFake(cb => {
  cb(undefined, 5);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need `callsFake()` to get `getUserByID` tocall the callback so that you can test that `res.statusCode` is set properly. The sinon function you want here is `stub.yields()` which is made specifically for this purpose and will call the first callback passed to the function with arguments you provide.

```
var getUserByIDStubE = sinon.stub(dbService, 'getUserByID').yields([null, 5]);
```

This will cause the callback you are passing to `getUserByID` to be called with no error and a value of 5 or whatever value you want to test.

Comment: Last thing, if my method takes in a parameter such as "req.dbService.getUserByID(req.body, ...)" such as req.body, how would I stub this parameter with Sinon?

Thank you! I will upvote.